# Get the cause of a maven build failure with Maven embedder

Tags: java, maven, maven-embedder

I am able to run maven build with the following code

```
MavenCli mavenCli = new MavenCli();
int result = mavenCli.doMain(goals.toArray(new String[goals.size()]), pom, System.out, System.out);
```

Basically result is equal to 0 if build is successful, and 1 otherwise. Is there any way to get the cause of a build failure?

Comment: Can you tell why are you trying to call Maven from a java program and not from console or from within a CI solution?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am sorry, but this is a very long story.